# Бот гостит у другого бота

Tags: aiogram, бот, telegram

Задача такая:
Есть +100500 ботов, все мои но созданы для других, я их сам задеплоил и сопровождаю, и лично в этих ботах не нахожусь.
Хочу поместить в них другого бота, которому каждое утро будет приходить месага, что, мол все норм, мы не вылетели, работаем, а тот единственный, уже мне в личку пересылает эту месагу, ну чтобы я сам не находился в этой куче ботов.
Вопрос как одному боту войти в другой? (варианты с общественными каналами не подходят).

Comment: Никак. Боты не видят друг друга, для этого можно юзерботом воспользоваться.